# Polybase external data source using ODBC, login failed error

Tags: sql-server, odbc, sql-server-2019, polybase

Using SQL Server 2019 Enterprise Edition (CU14)

I am attempting to use Polybase for reading data from a simple CSV text file.

When executing the `create external data source` I get the error "*Msg 46721, Level 20, State 1 Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication*."

The statement I'm using is:

```
create external data source datasourcename
with (
  location = 'odbc:\\localhost',
  connection_options='Driver=Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv); Dbq=d:\data\; ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly;',
  pushdown=off,
  credential = <credential name> -- < On DEV server it works both with/without this
);
```

This actually **works** on my development server, however on the production server it is throwing this error and I can't find a solution. Not really sure *what* is trying to be logged in to!

On the Dev server (also SQL server 2019/CU14) I can even leave off the *credential* option and it still works.

Both servers are using the same domain account for the SQL Server service and Polybase services, I have defined the credential identically as:

```
 create database scoped credential <credential name> with identity = 'Sql Server service domain account', secret = 'domain account password';
```

I don't think it's relevant but the production server is an Availability-Group secondary replica where I'm trying a simple proof-of-concept to test reading a CSV file and inserting data into TempDB.

On both my Dev server and Production server the file I'm trying to read is located in a folder on a local drive. The drive & folder has full control permissions for the SQL Server Service account.

Both servers have the same odbc driver installed, version 16.00.4999.1000

I have tried adding "trusted_connection=Yes and No" to the connection_options.

Connecting with SSMS I have tried using my own *domain account* and the SQL Server *sa* account.

I have installing the "Kerberos Configuration Manager" and connecting to the production server to check the SPNs and it reports "status good".

I have tried adding "DisableLoopbackCheck" registry key on the server.

So far nothing has worked and I'm at a loss as to what else to try.

Comment: I'm surprised it's even accepting `'odbc:\\localhost'` instead of `'odbc://localhost'`. Have you checked the `HOSTS` file on the production server(s) yet to see if somebody has created an entry for `localhost` that points to something other than `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Tried with `//` also and with something other than localhost too inc 127.0.0.1, same error unfortunately. I think there's something more fundamental wrong as I can put gibberish for the connection options and still get the login failed error. Possibly there's something *somewhere* that needs security permissions perhaps, but what...

Comment: I managed to finally uncover the reason for the error. Locating the Polybase logs (because the server is a 2019 upgrade of 2016 they were located under mssql.13 folder). Seems polybase was installed with the DWConfiguration being part of the availability group cluster, which means on this replica server the database is read only Doh. That was the reason for the (misleading) error

Answer (score 0):

The external data source definition is wrong: use forward slashes, don't use localhost, the odbc string is missing the curly braces, application intent is not a property of the odbc, and you don't need a credential. See this link for an example: https://36chambers.wordpress.com/2022/02/21/polybase-versus-flat-files/

Comment: Thanks for the link - I've seen examples of the data source with and without curly braces - adding them makes no difference (works fine without them on my DEV server), nor the forward vs back slashes.

Comment: What about removing the application intent and the credential?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *removing the application intent*? Trying *create external data source* with or without the credential makes no difference. If I try with `location=''` the error is "External option 'LOCATION' is not valid." as you'd expect - however putting *anything* for the location (eg location='xxx' ) returns the *Login Failed* error.

Comment: You have the following, but ApplicationIntent is not a valid property, try removing it: connection_options='Driver=Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv); Dbq=d:\data\; ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly;'

Comment: Ah ok yes, removed that (it came from some example I'd used previously). no change, in fact I can remove the connection options completely and still get login failed, it's as if it doesn't get to even use the settings supplied before this login failed message. Something fundamental is failing somewhere and I suspect it's a red herring since both the service account, my domain account, the sa account etc all have all privileges and the same accounts are used on the Dev server with no problem. Puzzling.

Comment: I managed to finally uncover the reason for the error. Locating the Polybase logs (because the server is a 2019 upgrade of 2016) they were located under mssql.13 folder). Seems polybase was installed with the DWConfiguration being part of the availability group cluster, which means on this replica server the database is *read only* Doh. That was the reason for the (misleading) error.

Comment: I'm glad that you found the issue, please convert it to a separate answer so other people can benefit from it, and mark it as the resolution.